# Set values of LI tag in HTML

Tags: html

I have a Ordered list that I need to set the # values for. Something like:

```
<ol>
 <li ShowValue=34>apple</li>
 <li ShowValue=45>pear</li>
 <li ShowValue=55>car</li>
</ol>
```

So that they display with the numbers I assign

```
34.apple
45.pear
55.car
```

Is there a way to tell the LI what number it should show?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use HTML 4.01 you can do this:

```
<ol>
  <li value="34">apple</li>
  ...
</ol>
```

Bu notice that [this is deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/lists.html#h-10.2).

Comment: But [un-depreciated in HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#attr-li-value)

Comment: But the `value` of an `li` is not the same as the value of a form field. "The `value` attribute, if present, must be a _valid integer_ giving the _ordinal value_ of the list item."

Answer (score 4):

What about taking an unordered list and writing the number inside?

```
<ul>
    <li>34. apple</li>
    <li>45. pear</li>
    <li>55. car</li>
</ul>
```

You would have to hide the list's bullets then. Use

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

for that.

Comment: It *is* possible but deprecated.

Comment: Problem with 'I.. just edited my post' is that we now don't know what lutz meant with it's remark.

Answer (score 3):

The HTML approach:

```
<ol start="34">
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>pear</li>
    <li>car</li>
</ol>
```

this is deprecated in HTML4 in favour of CSS generated content:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .mylist { counter-reset: mycounter 34; }
    .mylist li { counter-increment: mycounter; list-style-type: none; }
    .mylist li:before { content: counter(mycounter) ". "; }
</style>

<ol class="mylist">
    <li>apple</li> ...
</ol>
```

This has some advantages in that you can also let a list run through without resetting (for if you have 33 other things in a previous list). However it doesn't work in IE6/IE7 so you can forget it for now.

The deprecation of `<ol start>` (and `<li value>`) is a matter of some controversy. Many (myself included) believe it to have been a mistake, as the list number is closer to content than presentation in the common case of a continued list. Whilst the HTML hack is admittedly nasty, IMO the CSS workaround is worse.

Anyhow, HTML5 re-includes these attributes so they are not going away. If continued `<ol>`s are a necessity, I'd stick with the HTML `start`/`value` attributes, and use either the HTML4/XHTML1 Transitional DOCTYPE or the HTML5 one.

Comment: FYI, this option is a PERFECT solution when you're making posts online in editors that have "limited HTML support".

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how the HTML is being generated. If it's static, then simply typing the values in would work:

```
<li value="35">35.apple</li>
```

If it's generated server-side, then you can add it in the server code.

The third way would be to use jQuery to modify the contents after it has been rendered.

Comment: This would output `35. 35.apple`.

Comment: You can't alter the content of an automatically-generated list marker from JavaScript though... you'd have to hide the marker completely and put the number in the main content, as in Alex's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an attribute to output a numeric value.  That is not what the list items are for and in using it in this manner is violating the elements semantics.  The ol element is an ordered list.  That means the list items in that list have an enumerated meta data value that represents an ordering opposed to an unordered list, which has no meta-data enumeration, and therefore is merely a collection of list items without regard for the position of a list item relative to the other list items.

What you are attempting is a presentation feature.  HTML is not a presentation language.  Use should use CSS:

```
#custom-item:before {
    content: "35.";
}
```

See this article for more information: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/taminglists/