# How to get list item (<li>) marker/label declared in list-style-type?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

Lets say I have a list like this:

```
<ul style="list-style-type: upper-latin;">
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>Ipsum</li>
</ul>
```

(`list-style-type` might be anything - upper-roman, katakana, lower-greek)

`list-style-type: upper-latin;` will put a alphabet letter (starting from A) in front of every list item.
Is there a way to get this letter for any given list item? I can probably iterate over list using jQuery [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) or similar.

Or, maybe there is way to extract markers from style?

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800210/possible-to-get-list-item-li-label-with-javascript) works only for Latin alphabet lists.

Comment: "The answer here works only for Latin alphabet lists." --- and why it doesn't work for you?

Comment: upper-latin generates exactly the same letters as lower-alpha. Only for uppercase you have to start from 65 instead of 97.
http://www.ascii-code.com/

Comment: I forgot to mention, the list-style-type is unknown. It might be upper-roman or katakana.

Comment: Ok, my bad, I was too fast. Concluding there was only one type. I only see a hardcoding way at the moment. Get the the list-style-type and depending on the type get the sequence from a list that you created. But hardcoding is a word I dont like.

Comment: have you checked if this css solution sugested here would work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770482/set-values-of-li-tag-in-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to get this letter for any given list item?

Yes. You can read the `list-style-type` and generate what characters are showing for each style type. Which character is shown for a specific item number and style type could vary across browsers though.

> Or, maybe there is way to extract markers from style?

No. (At least not currently)

Some useful stuff for writing a generator:

- [List of Unicode characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters)
- [List-generator in all `list-style-types`](http://jsfiddle.net/rPy8n/)
- [Numbers to roman numerals in Javascript](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/javascript-roman-numeral-converter)

Also, many of the list-styles are uppercase versions of other list styles. Could be good to know then that `myString.toUpperCase()` works on unicode characters as well. :)

Comment: Is it possible to generate characters for specific styles? How? Or I have to store all the characters sets for every style locally and map them to style names (doesn't sound too exciting)?

Comment: They would quite possibly be predictable, you'd have to explore each character set to search for patterns. Greek for example follows the unicode `α, β, γ...` or  `U+03B1, U+03B2, U+03B3...` Helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Comment: you should use something like @Jan propose, there is no way to do something like `$(li).('list-style-value');` :/

Comment: @Tom I'm afraid so. I thought that there would be something more simpler or elegant, but, oh well =)

Comment: Added some resources to my answer.