# Get computed number of ordered list item

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is there a way to get the content of an ordered list item's number?

```js
var list = document.getElementById('list');
list.style.listStyleType = 'upper-roman';
```

```html
<ol class="list" id="list">
  <li class="list__item">apple</li>
  <li class="list__item">banana</li>
  <li class="list__item" id="target">orange</li>
  <li class="list__item">pear</li>
</ol>
```

That will produce a list of items like this.

```
I. apple
II. banana
III. orange
IV. pear
```

### Is there a way to get the `III` string of text of the `#target` list item?

EDIT:

Roman characters here are just an example. I'd like the ability to access to the content provided by any of the `list-style-type` options.

Comment: So do you want the strong "orange"?

Comment: @mikestreety: No, see the last sentence of the question: He/she wants the string `"III"`.

Comment: I'm mistaken on the understanding the question. Sorry, my fault

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651739/how-to-access-css-generated-content-with-javascript

Comment: prob dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063095/how-to-get-list-item-li-marker-label-declared-in-list-style-type

Comment: Maybe retrieving the `computedStyle` of the `content` of the `::marker` pseudo-element or something like that will eventually work.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I can think of doing this is the following:

1) Get the index of the item (e.g. 3)

2) Have a function like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9083076/1324321

3) Run the index through the function

Comment: yes, this would work for the roman numerals example, however i was more interested in something that would allow me to access the content in any of options provided by the api.

Comment: I've updated the question with that clarification, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I created a jsfiddle **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/8g3dLpnj/2/)** which can display the chosen selection to the user. Although javascript is not holding this as a string, I first find the index of the selected list item, then I recreate a list of that one item with the "start" attribute being set to that index.

Here is the HTML:

```
<ol>

  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li id="active">third</li>
  <li>Fourth</li>
</ol>

<br/>
<br/>
<div id='selected'>
</div>
```

And the JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var intt = $('li').index($('#active')) + 1;
  $('#selected').html('<ol start="' + intt + '"><li></li></ol>');
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8g3dLpnj/2/)**

Comment: This does a good job of extracting the value and putting it somewhere else, but it does not get the value as a string so that anything can be done with it further. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the start attribute and iterate all list elements.

```js
var list = document.getElementById('list'),
    start = list.start || 0;

list.style.listStyleType = 'upper-roman';
Array.prototype.forEach.call(list.getElementsByTagName('li'), function (a, i) {
    if (a.id === 'target') {
        console.log(i + start);
        console.log(a.innerHTML);
    }
});
```

```html
<ol class="list" id="list" start="5">
  <li class="list__item">apple</li>
  <li class="list__item" >banana</li>
  <li class="list__item" id="target">orange</li>
  <li class="list__item">pear</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question really. Thanks though!

Comment: I've updated the question to highlight the string I'm ultimately attempting to access. Please see the bolder text: it is neither the `start` + `index` value, nor the fruit name, but rather the `III`.